# I want to replace data continuously by the number of specific columns

Tags: python, dataframe, preprocessor

I want to replace raw values ​​continuously based on a specific column in my data frame as shown below.

Input,

[image: 1]

Expected Output,

[image: 1]

I tried to solve it like this, but it didn't work. Can you help me?

```
df = data
df1 = df[:]    

a = 0
while a <= df.shape[0]:
    if pd.isnull(df['REPEAT'].iloc[a]) == False :
        for j in range(int(df['REPEAT'].iloc[a])) : 
            df1.iloc[a+j] = df.iloc[a]
    a = a+j+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna` with `ffil` method

```
df.fillna(method='ffil')
```

more details in this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
In your case you can try this code:

```
i = 0
while i < df.shape[0]:
    if not np.isnan(df.loc[i,"REPEAT"]):
        rep = int(df.iloc[i]["REPEAT"])
        df.loc[i+1:i+rep,"A"] = df.iloc[i]["A"]
        df.loc[i+1:i+rep,"b"] = df.iloc[i]["b"]
        df.loc[i+1:i+rep,"REPEAT"] = rep
        i = i + rep
    i = i + 1
```

but if the date_time is the index of your dataframe, you have to reset the index before trying this code

Comment: this may not result in what OP needs this will fill all the rows, u might need to apply loc filter.

Comment: @Sushanth I edited the answer by adding the solution of his case

Comment: I got the idea from your answer and solved it like this. Thank you.

Comment: df = data[:]
df1= df[:]
i = 0
while i < df1.shape[0]:
    if not np.isnan(df.iloc[i][:]["REPEAT"]):
        rep = int(df.iloc[i]["REPEAT"])
        df1.iloc[i+1:i+rep][:] = df1.iloc[i+1:i+rep][:].fillna(df.iloc[i][:])
        i = i + rep
    i = i + 1    
data = df1[:]